# How do you access Azure runbook storage?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

I have a powershell script that downloads a file from an RESTApi, which works fine outside of a runbook.  It downloads the file to c:\temp on my local machine.  When I run the runbook, it has an issue with the path c:\temp. I need the files on a drive so I can place them on an FTP server, which I also want to incorporate into the runbook.  How does one access storage in the runbook?  I saw an article about $env:TEMP , but don't know how to incorporate that into the powershell script.

Have tried the variable $env:TEMP in powershell script but it is not working.

Comment: You do know that whatever you store in your runbook will be gone as soon as the script ends right?

Comment: What is the code you have tried so far? Could you share it here! @Jeremy Reynolds

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up wrt file being removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `ls` and `pwd` in a test runbook shows that it is running in the folder `C:\app`

Do you have to use `C:\Temp`? Could you not just place your files in the running directory by using `.\`? I was able to create a file in that directory in my test script.

Comment: This will solve my issue,  Thanks.  I can place the files in any folder as long as I can access them while the runbook is running.